# Unable to format internal drive as APFS on 2018 MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, disk-utility, mojave, apfs

I’ve recently ran a semi-routine clean install on my 2018 MacBook Pro. This involves the following steps (in the given order):

- Creating a USB installer with the latest macOS Mojave 10.14.2.
- Booting into the USB (Pressing <kbd>Option</kbd> key on boot).
- Using the Disk Utility, erasing the Disk and formatting it as APFS with a GPT Partition scheme.
- Using the Terminal, unmounting the disk `diskutil unmountDisk disk0`, where `disk0` is the internal NVME drive.
- Using the Terminal, running `gpt destroy disk0` where `disk0`.
- Using the Terminal, running `diskutil zeroDisk disk0`.
- Once that process is complete, I use the Disk Utility application to reformat as APFS, and install macOS.

Nothing super crazy, maybe a little redundant in steps, maybe a little overkill, maybe a little unnecessary.

Recently, however, on the final step where I format it as a APFS drive, it fails in creating the APFS container and says `Internal State Error`. It appears to first format as `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)` then create an APFS container, then add a APFS Volume. It fails when adding a Volume with **An internal error occurred**.

I have tried many things, including:

- Securely erasing the drive `diskutil secureErase 0 disk0`.
- Simply zeroing the disk again `diskutil zeroDisk disk0` (I’m not sure what the actual difference between these two are).
- Reformatting the drive as other things, such as `ExFAT` / `FAT` / `MacOS Journaled`, then trying to format as `APFS`.
- Reformatting the drive through the command line instead: `diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ NAME disk0` → `diskutil apfs createContainer /dev/disk0s2` → `diskutil apfs addVolume disk0s2 APFS NAME` (It fails here with **Error starting APFS Container creation: The given disk is not an APFS Container Reference (-69630)**, even though I just made a container there. Also, trying to add a volume to where it actually made the container (i don't know what it does this) `diskutil apfs addVolume disk24 APFS NAME` also fails with **Error: -69624: Unable to add a new APFS Volume to an APFS Container**
- Reformatting the drive using this: `diskutil eraseDisk APFS NAME disk0`
- Restarting and trying these again.
- Using a different installer than the USB (The one from <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, and whatever the other combo is), and trying these again.

All end up at the same thing - the final step fails. I would expect especially after a secure wipe that the drive would be removed from whatever state it was put in, or that if it was a bug with the 10.14.2 installer, that it still wouldn’t happen again in the High Sierra installer. In Disk Utility, I’m left with the following structure:

```
- APPLE SSD AP(...) // “Container disk24” takes up all space 

   - Container disk24 // or some other number. “Used” is 207.2MB and “Free” is 1TB.
```

Please note even though I can format as `JHFS+`, it won’t let me install the OS to such a formatted volume. The installer tells me this computer forces me to only install on APFS formatted volumes.

Any direction is greatly appreciated. I have never had such a silly problem before. Also, note that I have no Time Machine backup.

Comment: The most straight forward approach is the command `diskutil partitiondisk disk0 1 gpt apfs "My Mac" 0`

Comment: @DavidAnderson I have tried this after a disk cleanup and unfortunately I get the following: `newfs_apfs: unable to format volume inside /dev/disk0s2: No space left on device`, `Could not mount disk0s2 after erase`, and finally, `Error: -69832: File system for matter failed`.

Comment: have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Below are three examples of how to erase the drive and create a APFS volume named `MyVolume`. You only need to follow one of the examples.

- The commands given below create a `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)` partition, then reformat to `APFS`.

  ```
  diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ dummy GPT disk0
  diskutil apfs create disk0s2 MyVolume
  ```
- The commands given below create a `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)` partition, then convert to `APFS`.

  ```
  diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ myVolume GPT disk0
  diskutil apfs convert disk0s2
  ```
- The commands given below create a `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)` partition, then convert to an empty APFS container. Finally an `APFS` volume is added to the container..

  ```
  diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ dummy GPT disk0
  diskutil apfs createContainer disk0s2
  Container=$(diskutil info disk0s2 | grep Container)
  diskutil apfs addVolume "${Container##* }" APFS myVolume
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I suffered this issue last year and I've dug deeper and managed to find a fix! (I had to send it to apple when it happened to me), old posts have been archived but hope this helps if anyone has the issue in the future! :)

https://torbet.co/posts/Mac-Error-fix ([archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20210530211809if_/https://torbet.co/posts/Mac-Error-fix))

Comment: Please summarize the solution directly in your answer so others don't need to follow a link to get to it.