# MacOS Cannot format to APFS

Tags: macos, apfs

I am experiencing an identical problem to the one in: [Unable to format internal drive as APFS on 2018 MacBook Pro](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/346794/unable-to-format-internal-drive-as-apfs-on-2018-macbook-pro)

However this thread in unanswered and unresolved

My internal drive can format to everything except APFS, I have tried troubleshooting via linux, and simple disk utility. Fsck and first aid both report no problems and this is driving me insane!! help desperately needed!

Answer (score 3):

I do not know if you read my answer to the question you refer to? The command `diskutil apfs createcontainer disk0` should have failed. You are suppose to create the container inside a partition (or two partitions where each partition is on a different drive). You specified `disk0` which usually is the primary internal drive on a Mac. Maybe you were able to create the container, but being unable to create a volume would not be an unexpected result.

Below are the commands from [my other answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/346794/unable-to-format-internal-drive-as-apfs-on-2018-macbook-pro/387218#387218).

```
diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ dummy GPT disk0
diskutil apfs createContainer disk0s2
Container=$(diskutil info disk0s2 | grep Container)
diskutil apfs addVolume "${Container##* }" APFS myVolume
```

The first command creates the partitions. The second command create a APFS container in the second partition. The third and fourth commands creates an APFS volume in the APFS container.

Comment: Yes I attempted that and replied on the old post. all is fine until I add the volume, in which case I get an error 69624 unable to add APFS Volume to container. https://imgur.com/a/zXcrjYx

Comment: OK, I admit I should have realized the container would not be `disk1`. Obviously, you figured this out. What I originally suggested was to execute the first two commands, then post the output from the commands `diskutil apfs list` and `gpt -r show /dev/disk0`. This would show if space was available for a APFS volume. Also, what is the model/year of your Mac? How are you booting to macOS Recovery? I was wondering if booting to a different version would fix the problem.

Comment: This is on a 2018 MBP 15, I have tried from internet recovery and bootable USB. I have tried your updated commands and they still result in an error 69624, still specifically adding the volume to the container.

Answer (score 0):

Why not boot to recovery, erase and reinstall?

- [How to restore my MacBookPro 6,2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/387181/how-to-restore-my-macbookpro-6-2)

There is zero need for a command line approach if you have a complicated APFS / CS / diskutil situation and aren't comfortable posting your precise setup and a quick explanation of which one command you need some explanation or help with.

Comment: I cannot erase to apfs and get error 69624 when diskutil attempts to add the volume.

Comment: @show me the disk utility window screen shot that gets you that error? Step 7 of the erase should look like this image - https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/macos/Catalina/macos-catalina-recovery-mode-disk-utility-erase-volume.jpg

Comment: https://imgur.com/YPhNmAb

Comment: any ideas? it is specifically adding the volume to the container

Comment: Well, if you have a container, then post the output from `diskutil apfs list`. It might also be helpful to post the output from `gpt -r show /dev/disk0`.

Comment: @DavidAnderson sorry for the late reply, here is the output: https://imgur.com/a/SZpMkF1

Comment: @DavidAnderson I see that disk0 has 'no uuid', could this be the issue?