# MAC UNABLE TO FORMAT TO APFS

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, disk-utility, apfs, disk-format

I hate to spam and reopen old issues but this is urgent!!

I am experiencing an identical problem to the one in: [Unable to format internal drive as APFS on 2018 MacBook Pro](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/346794/unable-to-format-internal-drive-as-apfs-on-2018-macbook-pro)

My internal drive can format to everything except APFS, I have tried troubleshooting via linux, and simple disk utility. Fsck and first aid both report no problems and this is driving me insane!! help desperately needed!

Comment: If this becomes different with an edit, please flag for reopening after casting a coupe reopen votes.

Comment: @bmike the old issue in question in unresolved

Comment: @GuyTorbet: Sorry I am blocked from being able to answer your question. I did post an answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/346794/unable-to-format-internal-drive-as-apfs-on-2018-macbook-pro/387218#387218). Let me know if the answer helps with your problem.

Comment: @DavidAnderson sorry I don't have enough reputation to comment on that post. I tried all 3 solutions and got stuck during all 3 when attempting to add the volume to the container (error 69624).

Comment: @DavidAnderson I can create an APFS Container however macOS is "unable to add APFS Volume to container"

Comment: @DavidAnderson and Guy - fix the old question - that one is open for answers. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/386948/macos-cannot-format-to-apfs